# How to retrieve incoming parameters using C#?

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core

I am integrating with waboxapp API ([link](https://www.waboxapp.com/assets/doc/waboxapp-API-v2.pdf)) using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0.

Some parameters have been posted like this

```
contact[uid], contact[name], contact[type], message[uid], message[body] etc...
```

I have tried the following code :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(string uid, string token, List<string> contact)
 {
     foreach (string item in contact) {
         Common.TestEmail(uid, token);
     }

     return View();
 }
```

What is the proper way to retrieve incoming parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `waboxapp`, its request is **Standard HTTP format (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)**. Try to follow steps below:

1. Model

   ```
   public class Waboxapp
   {
       public string Token { get; set; }
       public Contact Contact { get; set; }
   }
   public class Contact
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Type { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Action

   ```
       [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult WaboxappFromForm([FromForm]Waboxapp waboxapp)
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```
3. Request
   [image]
4. Result 
   [image]

Comment: Thank you Tao, what shall I do if we have this scenario : message[body][text]